# The text on two columns is invisible in chrome

Tags: css

The text appears only in the first column, this is the example of code:

```html
<div STYLE="display:inline-block;-webkit-column-count:2;-moz-column-count:2;column-count:2;-webkit-column-gap:0;-moz-column-gap:0;column-gap:0;height:100;width:100%;background-color:red;">
  <div STYLE="padding:10px;-webkit-column-count: 2 ; -moz-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;overflow:auto;display:inline-block;position:relative;height:auto;width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
  </div>

  <div STYLE="padding:10px;-webkit-column-count: 2 ; -moz-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;overflow:auto;display:inline-block;position:relative;height:auto;width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
  </div>

  <div STYLE="padding:10px;-webkit-column-count: 2 ; -moz-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;overflow:auto;display:inline-block;position:relative;height:100px;width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
  </div>

  <div STYLE="padding:10px;-webkit-column-count: 2 ; -moz-column-count: 2;column-count: 2;overflow:auto;display:inline-block;position:relative;height:auto;width:100%;background-color:#FFFFFF;border: 1px solid #000000;">
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
    <BR>TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT-TEXT
  </div>
```

Comment: use `white-space: pre` and don't use BR

Comment: Is there a reason you used column-count instead of divs? Or even a table?

Comment: unfortunately I do not speak English and I'm struggling to understand.
The reason is that I want to have a table with the divs in the column and the text in the divs in the column

Answer (score 0):

The `overflow` attribute, coupled with nested column layouts, appears to be to blame.

First, let's setup a simpler, cleaner version of the problem.

Run the snippet and note that while the borders of the elements are visible, the contents of the second column are not visible (testing in Chrome 62.0.3202.89).

```css
.outer-split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.inner-split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-split">
  <div class="inner-split">
    column 1
    <br> column 1
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 2
    <br> column 2
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 3
    <br> column 3
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 4
    <br> column 4
  </div>

</div>
```

Take away the `overflow` attribute, and the content is visible.

```css
.outer-split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  -webkit-column-gap: 0;
  -moz-column-gap: 0;
  column-gap: 0;
}

.inner-split {
  -webkit-column-count: 2;
  -moz-column-count: 2;
  column-count: 2;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-split">
  <div class="inner-split">
    column 1
    <br> column 1
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 2
    <br> column 2
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 3
    <br> column 3
  </div>

  <div class="inner-split">
    column 4
    <br> column 4
  </div>
</div>
```

My guess is that the due to the nested column layout, the browser is calculating that all of the content is "overflow" and therefore hides it. Setting `overflow:visible` causes the hidden content to display.

I hesitate to say that this is a bug; it appears that the browser is allocating the space for the content but still clipping it. I tried giving the contents explicit height/width (see [Advanced Example](https://jsfiddle.net/b8uzvk74/)), but the text is still hidden.

[image]

Comment: Yes ... the problem is overflow, I also noticed it :-(

Comment: @corradox - I think the solution is to not use nested column layouts like this. You could probably use flexbox for the outer layout instead.

Comment: I tried it as Tim Medora explains, but I lay down all the layout.
Meanwhile, I do not have the chrome to put the columns and wait for some solution.

excuse me for english: google translator